# Transfer SC2 Installation from Mac OSX to PC

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

I am trying to transfer the Starcraft II install folder from Mac OSX to a Windows PC. The disk didn't work on my Windows PC as it stopped at 51% but it installed perfectly on the Mac computer. The "Starcraft II" folder is in my Program Files (I put it there, by copying it directly from he OSX install). Is there any way I can make the application itself work on Windows without having to download the client? The internet where I am is very slow and expensive, and I don't want to download a 6-12GB file. Thanks much!

Comment: I don't think there are 2 different clients for mac/windows for no reason. Saying, a Mac installation won't run on a windows client.

Comment: I had the same issue on release date. Either just try to install again or try to copy the whole DVD on your computer. Create a new folder SC2 on your Desktop. Open the DVD and copy all files to the new folder. Start your installation from the folder.

Comment: If your disk won't work then your only solution is to use online installer.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes. You will have to download some things, however.**

First, download the windows installer from blizzard.net. Let it start up and initialize the install - Once it gets to 1% of the actual download, you can close it.

Once it's closed, copy all of the data files from the OS X install over the newly created datafiles in the windows install. This only matters for files that have the same name and folder structure, so drag & drop is usually sufficient as long as the folders are merged. Tell it 'yes' on overwriting any files.

Start the installer back up, and let it rescan and continue the install. It won't be 100% done, but it should be very close. Just let it finish downloading the last bit from the internet.

This method works for SC2, WoW, and D3, and it works both ways. I use it frequently when I have an up-to-date blizzard game on my windows desktop, and need to make a copy on my mac book pro for when I travel. Mind if you're using OS X to do the copy, because it likes to replace folders instead of merging them when they have the same name.

There is no way to make the actual code of the client work 100% on another operating system, but this will save you the bulk of the download.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make compiled code for OSX run on a windows machine without recompiling or emulating.

If you run a Mac OSX emulator/virtual machine inside your windows machine, then the Mac OSX version will run inside that virtual OSX environment.

However, as Darth Android points out, it seems you can copy your data files across to an in-progress PC download. This means you only have to actually download the executable (which is small) rather than the entire game.

Comment: This is certainly a true statement in the generic sense, but it is an incorrect answer (not your fault, since you didn't have all the information). Both versions include nearly all the necessary executable files for both platforms, as per Darth Android's answer.

Comment: Technically, you do still have to download the client, just not the data files! :) But avoiding downloading the data makes that not a problem.